# The number of digits in an exponent of two

Tags: exponentiation, estimation

At the moment my area of research is Mersenne Primes. I am currently looking into a specifically large exponent, $\ 2^{112401533}-1$, and I can’t help but wonder how I would calculate how many digits a number like that would have. Has anyone got any ideas on ways to estimate the number of digits in large exponents of two? (Or any other number - the results do not have to be exact, but more akin to a smart estimate on the number of digits).

Comment: Look at $\log_{10}2^p$.

Comment: While that may be a suitable method for some, is there any way of doing this utilizing just the exponent (112401533)? (This is because your method may be slow on modern computers and I would rather like a method which is fast)

Comment: @sciencepiofficial, $\log_{10}2\approx0.3$, so the number of digits in $2^p$ is approximately $0.3p$. But it's not hard these days to get the *exact* number by using a calculator that computes $\log_{10}2$ to a large number of digits. (You need roughly as many digits of the log of $2$ as there are in the exponent $p$.)

Comment: @sciencepiofficial to emphasize the maths behind this... recognize that $\log_a b^c = c\log_a b$, so Angina's suggestion simplifies to $p \log_{10} 2$

Comment: Than you for the help

Comment: The only thing remaining is to recognize that the logarithm base $10$ tells you how many digits long something is.  More specifically, $\lfloor \log_{10} n\rfloor + 1$ is the number of digits in $n$ for natural number $n$.  (*E.g. $\log_{10}100 = 2$ so $100$ is $3$ digits long and similarly $\log_{10}105\approx 2.02$ so $105$ is also $3$ digits long while $\log_{10}98\approx 1.99$ so $98$ is $2$ digits long*)

Comment: Using the estimate $2^{10}\approx 10^3$ can give you a quick ball park estimate.

Comment: @scienceipofficial :  "is there any way of doing this utilizing just the exponent (112401533)?"  Of course not.  How would you could you distinguish the answers for $2^x$ and $9^x$ (say), without consulting the base?!

Comment: "your method may be slow on modern computers" Are you *kidding*??  *Mathematica* gives every digit in $0.00371$ seconds on a Mac laptop.